# How to transfer the model loaded by tf.loadFrozenModel in main thread to webworker

Tags: tensorflow, web-worker, tensorflow.js

Now I use the function tf.loadFrozenModel() to load the model in main thread,then i want to clone or transfer the loaded model to the webworker. How can i do it?
  the code in my github:
https://github.com/yiifanLu/webWorker

Answer (score 0):

It is better to download the frozen model directly in the worker. The reason being that on the version 10 and 11, there is not the `tf.models.modelFromJSON` for loading a model stringified which can be passed to the worker using `model.toJson`.

The following defines a model in the main thread. This model is saved in a file that is served by a local server. The worker can load and use it for predictions

```html
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@0.14.2/dist/tf.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        const worker_function = () => {

            onmessage =  async (event) => {
                console.log('from web worker')
                    this.window = this
                    importScripts('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/setimmediate@1.0.5/setImmediate.min.js')
                    importScripts('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@0.11.2')
                    tf.setBackend('cpu')
                    const model = await tf.loadModel('http://localhost:8080/model.json')
                    model.compile({loss: 'meanSquaredError', optimizer: 'sgd'});
                    
                    // Generate some synthetic data for training.
                    const xs = tf.tensor2d([1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 1]);
                    const ys = tf.tensor2d([1, 3, 5, 7], [4, 1]);

                    // Train the model inside the worker
                     await model.fit(xs, ys, {epochs: 10})
                     const res = model.predict(tf.tensor2d([5], [1, 1]));
                    // send response to main thread
                    
                    postMessage({res: res.dataSync(), shape: res.shape})
            };
        }
        if (window != self)
            worker_function();
    </script>
    <script>
    
        const model = tf.sequential();
        model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 1, inputShape: [1]}));
        
        const worker = new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(["(" + worker_function.toString() + ")()"], { type: 'text/javascript' })));
        (async() => {
            model.save('downloads://model')
        })()
       
        worker.postMessage({model : 'model'});
        worker.onmessage = (message) => {
            console.log('from main thread')
            const {data} = message
            tf.tensor(data.res, data.shape).print()
        }
    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: i want to load frozen model by loadFrozenModel(), not with loadModel()

Comment: Can import the tensorflowjs on the version 0.12.5  in the webworker?    the loadFrozenModel function launched on the version 0.12.5

Comment: @陆一凡,   `loadFrozenModel` is not part of the 0.10.3 version. Therefore you can't use it in the worker. Rather you can use `loadmodel` as demonstrated in the answer by supplying the topology (json file). It will directly use the weights (bin file), if it is placed in the same folder as the topology file

Comment: Depressing 。。。。。。。。

Comment: @陆一凡 could you elaborate more ?

Comment: I trained the model in tensorflow,then I convert it into tensorflow.js model.So I use loadFrozenModel() to load it .In order to make the main thread run smoothly,I want to use the webworker.But you said loadFrozenModel is not part of the 0.10.3 version,and you said the latest version of tensorflow.js is not supported in webworker.There is a method: I want to use loadFrozenModel() in main thread,the return value of loadFrozenModel() transfer to the webworker.Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @陆一凡 As I suggested, can you use `loadModel` instead of `loadFrozenModel` ?

Comment: I try to change the code.And do you know how to use webgl in webworker because it is slow with cpu?

Comment: @陆一凡, for now it is not possible to use webgl in the backend. If the answer helped don't forget to upvote it :)